ETA (electronic travel authorization) Israel
As of next year everyone who enters as a tourist in Israel is obligated to get an ETA. The application form ask first name. As you know many people have multiple first given names. And the application form is not clear if I should write down all first given names or just my first name.
For example my passport first given names says: Malka Sophia Kristina.
My second and third name are not listen as middle names in my passport but as first given names.
Do I need to write down all first given names?

What did the ETA-IL Help Center (eta@piba.gov.il) say when you asked them?

Unfortunately their English was not good enough. So I wonder if they know what I meant. So they see my second and third name as middle name, but they are listed as full given names. I wonder if when I write down all my first given names if thats a problem, because it is in my passport so technically it is correct.

Does it ask first name or does it ask for names?

If there’s space to input all 3 given names, and the application system allows it, I would do so. If there isn’t/it doesn’t, I would enter your first given name and your family name.

Most countries do not have a concept of “middle names”, and first name(s) and given name(s) are the same thing. If the form does not allow for middle name(s), and those name(s) appear on the passport (especially in the MRZ), you should probably enter all of them if it fits, though in practice they usually don’t care. I have 3 given names but most of the time only use one and I don’t remember it ever being a problem.

@Willeke: it only ask for first name. But Israel in general does not have the concept of multiple names/middle. It is less common.

@jcaron: it is fits I will write down all 3 names. Technically it is not wrong since it is under first given name and in my passport. So it will match what is says in my passport.

If asked for a first name (singular) I give my first name, if asked for names, (plural) I give all, as in my passport. Israel has a population from all over the world, so also with multiple given names.

@willeke: I received another e-mail from them and this is what they say: Dear Mr\Ms, You need to write the full name as it is shown in the passport.
To me that implies writing everything down.

Good luck if you have six given names and a 6 word family name. And some people have even more than that

@ Willeke lol, yeah I feel like they haven't thought about that when making the application form.

Machine-readable passports only have 30 characters for the name, including separators. Jewish Israeli names are typically just first-name surname, with middle name quite rare, so that's probably the focus of their name policy. Although Jews born in Western countries often have middle names.

OP posted this comment:

I received another e-mail from them and this is what they say: Dear Mr\Ms, You need to write the full name as it is shown in the passport. To me that implies writing everything down.

My original answer, which I still think is right:
If asked for a given name, singular, you are expected to fill out one of your given names, with the first as most common.
If asked for given names, plural, you should give as many as you have as long as they fit in the form.
Israel has had a very mixed population from the start as a nation, and visitors from even more cultural backgrounds.
The officials will be used to all common naming traditions, certainly 'first, middle, middle, family' as well as 'given, given, given, family'.
If the form has space for more than just one given name you can enter as many as fit.

I would take "as shown in the passport" as a strong indication that they want the entire "secondary identifier" (i.e., all of the given names) or as much of that as will fit.
